# On a peculiar use of the preposition/adverb "out"

Tags: prepositions, prefixes

*It* can be placed before the stem of many a word to produce verbs of a very distinctive kind! For example:

**out**date, **out**grow, **out**lay, **out**live, **out**match, **out**number, **out**run, **out**smart, **out**source, **out**strip, **out**weight, **out**wit,...

Is there another preposition/adverb in the English language that when used as a prefix originates such a noticeable amount of new **verbs**? Is there a generic term that can be used to refer to preposition/adverbs of this persuasion?

Thanks a lot for your patience and continued support!

Comment: Sure, the other half of the pair: *down* ;)

Comment: JHS, I second @DanBron, for instance, downvote! (JK)

Comment: @DanBron: What do you mean by "the other half of the pair"?

Comment: @J.H.S. I guess you've never been [*down and out*](http://smeegly.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Down-and-Out-in-Beverly-Hills.jpg)? Anyway, more seriously, almost any *directional* word will function as a very productive prefix to form new verbs.

Comment: It's unclear what your question really is.  Are you simply playing a game to see how many words one can think of in this category?

Answer (score 1):

*Out* is usable as an adverb, adjective or preposition.

*Out* is more frequently used as an adverb.

"*outdate, outgrow, outlay, outlive, outmatch, outnumber, outrun, outsmart, outsource, outstrip, outweight, outwit*" are all due to the adverbial action, rather than its prepositional effect.

- update, upward, uplift, upcast, upon, uppity, upkeep, upgive, updive, uprising, uprise, uppent, upstream, upshift
- overcome, overly, overbearing, overcast, overshadow, overconfident, overcast, overgrow, overlay, overrun, overfly, overkill, overdo, overeat, oversee, overuse

It's not over till it's over.

Comment: Upload, upshift, upsell ... etc.

Comment: @Blessed Geek: It has to be noted, though, that none of the following words is considered a verb (as of today): upon, uprising, uppent, overly, overbearing...

Comment: You forgot "upchuck".